# How to create a pos-edge Write pulse into a neg-edge pulse?

Tags: verilog

I have a data source signal that transitions high on the positive edge of its clock when it has data ready to be written.

I also have ram memory (running from the same clock) but expects it's write request signal to transition on the negative edge of the clock (and stay high until the following negative edge of the clock).

If I try driving the memory's wr_req directly from the data source then both the clock and wr_req transition at the same time and the memory doesn't get 
the data.

How can I delay the write pulse  such that it goes high (for one cycle) starting on the next negative edge of the clock?

Comment: one of possible ways is to turn on write_en, wait for an acknowledgement from the writer, then turn off the write_en.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you want:

```
reg blah;
always @(negedge clk) begin
    blah <= !foo;
end
```

Or even:

```
reg blah;
always @* begin
    if (!clk) begin
        blah = !foo;
    end
end
```

Simulated:

[image]

Comment: Does the potential race condition apply to both versions that Charles posted?    I tried it and works, the only tweak is that foo is an active high signal, so to create what looks like blah in the simulation above, I had to remove the inversion to blah, and then do:    reg blah_dly;  
assign final_wr_sig = blah & ~blah_dly;
always @(negedge clk) 
    blah_dly <= blah;

Comment: I'm not sure there's a race condition here. Especially with the nonblocking assignment. If there is and I'm missing it and would love some more detail